# Facebook Android SDK Audience Network NativeAdScrollView.CustomAdView missing

Tags: android, facebook, ads

I want to add a horizontal ad scrollview and followed the sample project. Source: [Facebook Audience Network Android docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/nativescroll)

```
    scrollView = new NativeAdScrollView(NativeAdHscrollActivity.this, manager,
        new NativeAdScrollView.CustomAdView() {
            @Override
            public View createView(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                View adView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unit, null);
                NativeAdSampleActivity.inflateAd(nativeAd, adView,
                    NativeAdHscrollActivity.this);
                return adView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyView(NativeAd nativeAd, View view) {
                nativeAd.unregisterView();
            }
    });
```

But the `new NativeAdScrollView.CustomAdView()` says "cannot resolve symbol 'CustomAdView'
I'm using SDK version 4.1.2

Comment: So how do we add custom view to native scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

The document you saw is out of date. CustomAdView does not exist any more in current sdk.